# Neo4j Cypher: Find isolated node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find nodes that do not connect with other nodes. (node A and node B in the picture below)

[image]

What I have tried is

```
MATCH (n:node) WHERE not ((n)<-[:connect]->(:node)) RETURN n
```

which seems to return only B.

How can I retrieve both A and B?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

This will work if you only care about `connect` relationships:

```
MATCH (n:node)
WHERE SIZE([(n)-[:connect]-(m:node) WHERE n <> m|1]) = 0
RETURN n
```

But if you want to pay attention to all relationship types, then use this:

```
MATCH (n:node)
WHERE SIZE([(n)--(m:node) WHERE n <> m|1]) = 0
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! However, this query also return C which I want to exclude.